# Comparing three strings

Tags: java, string, bluej

I know this question has probably been answered before, but im going round in circles. I can compare two strings fine but comparing three im not sure how. The purpose of my code is that the player has 3 cards, if two of the cards have the same suit then the player is awarded 5 extra points, if all three cards are the same then the player gets 10 points. i can add 5 points fine, but i cant make it add 10 only if all three are correct. can anyone help please?

here is my code

```
    private void setScore()
    {
        score = cardOne.setScore() + cardTwo.setScore() + cardThree.setScore();
        if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardTwo.getSuitName()))
        if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName()))
        if(cardTwo.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName()))
    {
        score = score + 5;
    }
        if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardTwo.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName())))
    {
        score = score + 5;
    }


    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `&&` operator?

Comment: Shove all three suit names into a `Set` and call `size()`.  Maybe even `score += (15 - theSet.size() * 5);`

Comment: To help make your code easier to follow, put the suitName's into a variable. It will shorten the if statement.

`String card1Suit = cardOne.getSuitName();
...
if (card1Suit.equals(card2Suit) && card1Suit.equals(card3Suit)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "and" operator `&&`:

```
if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardTwo.getSuitName()) && cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName()))
{
    score = score + 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardTwo.getSuitName()) && cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName())) 
{
    score += 5;
}
```

Basically, if card two is the same as card one and card three is the same as card one, card two and three will be the same as well. You can put them in one `if` statement and you can increment the score by five using `+=`

Answer (score 1):

You can use flow operators or (`||`) and and(`&&`);

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
Set<String> suits = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
        cardOne.getSuitName(),cardTwo.getSuitName(),cardThree.getSuitName()));
if(suits.size() == 1) score += 10;
else if(suits.size() == 2) score += 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the score as a integer data type, we can try comparing the card values as below..

```
private void setScore()
{
    int score = cardOne.setScore() + cardTwo.setScore() + cardThree.setScore();
    // check if any two cards are same
    if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardTwo.getSuitName())   ||
                    cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName()) ||
                    cardTwo.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName())){
        score +=  5;
        // check if all three cards are same
        if(cardOne.getSuitName().equals(cardTwo.getSuitName()) && cardTwo.getSuitName().equals(cardThree.getSuitName())){
            score +=  5;
        }
    }
}
```

hope the above code snippet helps..